# Suppose $A$ and $B$ have nonnegative real measure, can we conclude that $A \cup B$ have a nonnegative real measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying Sheldon Axler's "Measure, Integration and Real Analysis". I am struggling with the following question:(For the reference, this the Chapter 9A, Exercise1)

Prove or give a counter-example: If $v$ is a real measure on a measurable space $(X,S)$ and $A,B \in S$ are such that $v(A) \ge 0$ and $v(B) \ge 0$, then $v(A \cup B) \ge 0$.

**Definitions:** Let $(X,S)$ be a measurable space, i.e $X$ is a set and $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$. A function $v : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a *real measure* on measurable set $(X,S)$ if $v$ is countably additive, i.e $v(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} v(E_i)$ for all disjoint sequences  $E_1$ , $E_2$, .. in $S$.

**My attempt:** Using, countable additivity, we can write $v(A \cup B) = v(A \setminus B) + v(B \setminus A) + v(A \cap B) = v(A) + v(B) - v(A \cap B) $. Somehow, I could not conclude anything. My intuition says this is false, but unfortunately, I could not find a proper counter-example as well.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Let's put it more simply: can you find three real numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that $x_1+x_2>0$, $x_1+x_3>0$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3<0$?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio thank you for your comment.  I can choose $x_1= 3$ , $x_2 = -2$ and $x_3 = -2$. But, how can I show that, this is indeed a real measure?

Comment: Define for instance $X=\{1,2,3\},S=\mathcal P(X),v=3\delta_1-3\delta_2-2\delta_3.$

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got it:)